# How can I save credit card information along with the order details in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

One of my client want to save credit card information when any customer place the order. He does not want any payment gateway like **paypal/stripe etc**.

So that i have built custom plugin and built an user interface where user can fill their **ccno/cvc/expiry** date etc and place the order. when user place the order then getting payment-information 404 bad request. How can i solve this? Please suggest very urgent.

Comment: Magento 2 comes with a store payment option already prebuilt into it, please refer to https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/account-dashboard-stored-payment-methods.html

Comment: Hello Dava,

Thanks for your response. I know about this features but If i use this then i will have to use braintree to make the payment. But my requirement is like customer only need to fill the credit card information and place the order without using any payment gateway and card information should save along with generated order.  Means there shoudl not be any payment transaction

Comment: first check to see if you instance of magento already has an offline credit/debit card method which stores that data if not then you would need to create one and hook into the save order event and add in the additional data. this is not something i recommend you do. i would always suggest using a 3rd party to store any sort of customer credit/debit/account information.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to store credit card information directly on your website, as it can lead to security issues and can make your website a target for hackers. Instead, it is recommended to use a secure payment gateway like PayPal or Stripe that is designed to handle the storage of sensitive payment information.

If your client still wants to proceed with storing credit card information on their website, you will need to ensure that you are complying with all relevant security standards and regulations. Additionally, you will need to ensure that your custom plugin is integrated properly with Magento and that it is not causing any conflicts or errors with the payment information page.

To troubleshoot the 404 bad request error, you should check the Magento error logs and server logs to see if there are any error messages or indications of what might be causing the issue. You may also want to check the code for your custom plugin to ensure that it is properly configured and that it is not causing any conflicts with other modules or extensions.

However, it is highly recommended to discuss the risks and concerns associated with storing credit card information directly on the website with your client and advise them to use a secure payment gateway instead.